# java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host

Tags: android

Tengo este error en Android Studio y no puedo encontrar cual es el motivo

> "java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el
>   software en su equipo host."

**¿A que se debe este error?**

Comment: desconecta de internet tu computadora, reinicia y antes de conectar a internet abre android studio, y una vez que ya haya cargado ya puedes conectarte a internet, solucion rapida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estos problema puede ser resuelto simplemente cerrando Android studio y reiniciar de nuevo. Android studio  a veces no logra establecer una conexión con el emulador, así que esto puede ocurrir en algunos casos.

Comment: que extraño, ayer hasta reinicie la computadora y seguia el error y como ultimo recurso como ya no sabia que podia ser consulte aqui, hoy cerre el studio, volvi a abrir y ya anda, gracias

Answer (score 0):

> "java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el
>   software en su equipo host."

**¿A que se debe este error?**

Simplemente el dispositivo pierde la conexión, pueden ser varias las causas de este problema:

El [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) tuvo un error y necesita reiniciarse.
El cable no esta correctamente conectado.
El cable no funciona correctamente.

Si aseguras tener correctamente conectado tu dispositivos, reiniciando Android Studio puede no solucionar el problema, tienes que reiniciar el ADB, abriendo el Android Device Monitor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro, seleccionas el dispositivo, das clic en el triangulo señalado y seleccionas la opción `"Reset adb"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]