# Error de gradle al iniciar un proyecto

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Tengo un problema cada vez que creo un proyecto, al iniciar el gradle build(6.5) este me lanza un error **"Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.**" He intentado desactivando firewall de windows, windows defender y hasta reinstale android studio pero el problema persiste. La única solución que encontré es usar una versión de gradle menor(5.6.4) pero prefiero usar la recomendada por android studio. Espero puedan ayudarme.

**Error del programa:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs37k.jpg

**Idea Log:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILQM.jpg

Comment: Esa pregunta ya fue planteada hace un tiempo, revisa el siguiente enlace quizá te ayude!
https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24261/114296

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24261/java-io-ioexception-se-ha-anulado-una-conexi%c3%b3n-establecida-por-el-software-en-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un [open issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14094) introducido en la versión 6.4.1. Ocurre cuando activas el mobile hotspot de windows 10 y le conectas un dispositivo. Para solucionarlo simplemente debes desactivar esta feature o bien usar Gradle 6.4.0 o menor.

> prefiero usar la recomendada por android studio

No hay niguna versión recomendada por android studio. Pero para beneficiarte de todas las mejoras y bug fixes deberías usar la más reciente, que actualmente es 6.8.2 (publicada hoy).

Comment: Gracias!!, eso resolvió mi problema.

Comment: Me presentaba el mismo inconveniente y tenia activado el hotspot, solo lo desactive sincronizo sin problema.