# Gradle sync failed: Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: Android studio me marca este error y lo he desinstalado y he borrado la configuración anterior porque pensé que era un problema de compatibilidad pero no, no tengo idea que qué puede estar pasando, cree un proyecto nuevo cuando actualice a la ultima versión y nada, no tengo ninguna configuración ni nada de versiones anteriores y nunca me había dado este problema.]

Android studio me marca este error y lo he desinstalado y he borrado la configuración anterior porque pensé que era un problema de compatibilidad pero no, no tengo idea que qué puede estar pasando, cree un proyecto nuevo cuando actualice a la ultima versión y nada, no tengo ninguna configuración ni nada de versiones anteriores y nunca me había dado este problema.

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor

Comment: posible duplicado de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426136/error-de-gradle-al-iniciar-un-proyecto/426184)

Comment: Lo resolví instalando la versión anterior del android studio.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso pude resolverlo descargando el jdk 8 de https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html y luego configuré en las variables de entorno de windows: Variables de usuario->Path y agregué esta ruta (va a depender de donde se instale el jdk)-> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281 luego reinica el ordenador y listo. Buena suerte.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]